# Conditional Series Failing - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a basic multi series line chart I have been working on. I would like to accomplish something similar to the code below.

These are inside my `datasets[]`:

```
            {label: 'Branch '+b7,
            data: B7,
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
            },
            if(b8){
                {label: 'Branch '+b8,
                data: B8,
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                },
            }
            if(b9){
                {label: 'Branch '+b9,
                data: B9,
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                },
            }
```

As you may be able to see, I only want certain series to be created if their `b` variable exists. This currently will not work because of the `datasets` brackets.

I have not yet been able to find a solution other that setting all possible `b` variables to zero. That would not be acceptable for me.

**EDIT 1**

I Thought I would try creating multiple `datasets[]` like below. But now I cannot get the conditional statement to work. For `b0` its telling me unexpected `typeof`.

```
if(typeof b0 !== 'undefined'){
    datasets: [
    {label: 'Branch '+b0,
    data: B0,
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(204, 0, 0)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(204, 0, 0)',
    }]
},
if(b1){
    datasets: [ 
    {label: 'Branch '+b1,
    data: B1,
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(82, 235, 52)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(82, 235, 52)',
    }]
},
```

**EDIT 2**

I have attempted many ways of doing the `if` statement. Each attempt has yet to work. I have tried `if(typeof b !== 'undefined)'` as well as setting `x` to the `true` or `false` result of `typeof b` and attempting `if(x===true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you were attempting was not valid javascript syntax because you cannot put an `if` statement in the middle of an object declaration. Try something more like this:

```
var datasets = [
    {
        label: 'Branch '+b7,
        data: B7,
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
    }
];
if(b8) {
    datasets.push({
        label: 'Branch '+b8,
        data: B8,
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
    });
}
if(b9){
    datasets.push({
        label: 'Branch '+b9,
        data: B9,
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
   });
}

new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'),{
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: time,
        datasets: datasets
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly for me, thank you Ben!